# not only to, but also +ing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

is the following rule true?

This not only can be helpful **to apply** for a refund but also **applying** for a free ticket.

Comment: What rule?  Do you mean the "rule" that in a not only... but also construction, the first must use an infinitive but the second must use a gerund?

Answer (score 0):

The example sentence is incorrect - the two verbs linked by "not only ... but also ..." should be in the same form.

It is also at least a bit awkward because the "can be helpful" is sitting next to one of the verbs. It would be better reworded so that is before the "not only ...":

> This can be helpful not only to apply for a refund, but also to apply for a free ticket.

Or:

> This can be helpful not only for applying for a refund, but also for applying for a free ticket.

Note the extra "for" before "applying" in the second clause - since this came after the "not only", it needs to be repeated after the "but also".

Comment: it cannot be to and for at the same sentence like: This can be helpful not only for applying for a refund, but also to apply for a free ticket.

Comment: @DrDentMBR In general, the two phrases should "match" as much as possible - so either both should use to+infinitive, or both use for+gerund. Mixing them would be _understood_, but it would sound slightly odd, and probably be considered "incorrect" in a formal context.